# How to add loader gif between activities in android java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How do I make loading gif of 3 dots between activities that I already built? after pressing continue button I want loader to be showen for 5 sec and then redirect to the next activity.

Comment: Hi, please show us your code, without it no one can help you.

Comment: Can you share your code or screenshot what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: create custom loader and use https://medium.com/@ikhwan220397/load-image-and-gif-using-glide-7db77af3a77b gif code for same with 5 second Thread/Handler.

Comment: You should add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to create and show dialog on button click.

```
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

After this, you have to use handler to show dialog for 5 sec. and after that you have to hide dialog and call the intent.

```
new Handler(Looper.myLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            alert.hide();
            startActivity(new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class));
        }
    },5*1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a progress dialog

```
protected void showProgressDialog(String message) {
        _ProgressDialog.setMessage(message);
        _ProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        _ProgressBusy = true;
        _ProgressDialog.show();
    }
```

then have a countdown timer that dismisses it once time's up

```
 CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(6000, 1000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        showProgressDialog("Rebooting...");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        hideProgressDialog();
                    }
                };
                mCountDownTimer.start();
```

the hide is just a dismiss

```
protected void hideProgressDialog() {
        _ProgressDialog.dismiss();
        _ProgressBusy = false;
    }
```